# PREPARED STATEMENT in a WHILE loop

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, while-loop, prepared-statement

I have a table `autos` that has a column `name`, I want to check first 5 rows in the table and if `name` value is `"toyota"`, in table `mytable` write "yes", else write "no".
I write stored procedure, but `mysqli_error()` returns error in line, where I have `EXECUTE ...`.

If in `WHEN` I write not `PREPARED STATEMENT`, but directly the query, the procedure works.
Please see my code and tell me, where is it wrong?

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_auto()
BEGIN

DECLARE start INT;
SET start = 0;
PREPARE stmt FROM  ' SELECT name FROM autos ORDER BY id LIMIT ?,1 ';

WHILE start < 5 DO

    CASE 
        WHEN (EXECUTE stmt USING @start ) = 'toyota'
            THEN INSERT INTO mytable (log)  VALUES('yes');
        ELSE 
           INSERT INTO mytable (log)  VALUES('no');
    END CASE;
    SET start = start + 1;

END WHILE;
END;
```

Comment: What version of MySQL are you using?

Comment: Everything is understood, I do not know about this service, I am dont lazy tell "Thanks":)

Comment: Two years from your last comment and still no accepted answer? :|

Answer (score 2):

<sub>*(The suggestion about `EXECUTE` is removed as incorrect and potentially confusing.)*</sub>

The problem you are trying to solve with a stored procedure could in fact be solved without it, using an entirely different approach: just use a single `INSERT ... SELECT` statement instead:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (log)
SELECT
  CASE name
    WHEN 'toyota' THEN 'yes'
    ELSE 'no'
  END
FROM autos
ORDER BY id
LIMIT 5
```

That is, the above statement does the same as your stored procedure: it retrieves first 5 rows from `autos` and inserts 5 rows into `mytable`. Depending on the value of `name` it generates either `yes`es or `no`s.

Comment: **EXECUTE stmt USING start** not help me, Thanks of course for your variant,  **INSERT ... SELECT** statement is really simple, but I want understood how to use PREPARED STATEMENT in loop WHILE and on this write I stored procedure :)

Comment: Oh, I see. Perhaps you shouldn't have accepted my answer then. Please consider unaccepting it, then update your question with the **actual** error message that you receive when executing your stored procedure. I can't really answer your direct question, but maybe someone else might. But, again, make sure you **unaccept** my answer, or people may not be interested enough to look at your question if they see it has an accepted answer. (To unaccept an answer, you just click the green check sign next to it.)

Comment: For whatever reason, the `EXECUTE` function can only take variables prefixed with an `@` character, so `EXECUTE stmt USING start` will fail.

Comment: @RossSmithII. Thanks. I wonder if it was you who downvoted my answer. What do you think is (or "may be" if it wasn't you) particularly wrong with it so as to deserve a downvote?

Comment: Suggesting something that doesn't actually work (`EXECUTE ... start`) will be confusing to people. The rest of your answer is helpful, so maybe remove the first suggestion.

Comment: @RossSmithII: You might be right. At least, there's probably no point for that suggestion to stay now, when you've offered yours.

Answer (score 2):

Andriy M's `INSERT` statement is the most elegant solution, but if you still want to use a procedure, this will work:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_auto()
BEGIN
    DECLARE start INT DEFAULT 0;

    PREPARE stmt FROM 
        'SELECT name INTO @name FROM autos ORDER BY id LIMIT ?,1';

    WHILE start < 5 DO
        SET @start = start;
        EXECUTE stmt USING @start;
        IF @name = 'toyota' THEN
            INSERT INTO mytable (log)  VALUES('yes');
        ELSE 
            INSERT INTO mytable (log)  VALUES('no');
        END IF;
        SET start = start + 1;
    END WHILE;
END;
```

but, in this case, using a `CURSOR` would yield better performance:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_auto()
BEGIN
    DECLARE start INT DEFAULT 0;
    DECLARE b_not_found BOOL DEFAULT FALSE;

    DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
        'SELECT name FROM autos ORDER BY id LIMIT 5';

    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET b_not_found = TRUE;

    OPEN cur;

    loop1: WHILE start < 5 DO
        FETCH cur INTO @name;
        IF b_not_found THEN
            LEAVE loop1;
        END IF;

        IF @name = 'toyota' THEN
            INSERT INTO mytable (log)  VALUES('yes');
        ELSE 
            INSERT INTO mytable (log)  VALUES('no');
        END IF;
        SET start = start + 1;
    END WHILE;

    CLOSE cur;
END;
```